# savings calculation in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculation

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a calculation in javascript or jquery?
The percentage of costs must be set at 35%.
The average savings must be fixed at 19%.
An example would be: € 1.000.000 x 0,35 x 0,19 = € 66.500 saving

I've created this code here, but I am stuck on the calculation

```
<div id="calculator" class="calculator">
  <label class="title">Savings Calulator : Basic Compound Interest</label>
  <hr/>
  <br/>
  <label>Input ($)</label>
  <input type="number" id="principle" value="0" min="0">
    <br/>
  <label>Interest Rate (%)</label>
  <input type="number" id="interest-rate" value="0.35" min="0">
  </br>
    <label>Interest Rate (%)</label>
  <input type="number" id="interest-rate-two" value="0.19" min="0">
    <br/>
  <hr/>
  <div id="calc-result" class="result">
    $0
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/John_098/pen/BapVQjp

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In javascript & jQuery you can use `*` to multiply numbers, and `/` to divide them.

This is a simple script to calculate the 3 input values and output the result into the result div

```js
$("#calc").on("click", function(){
  let principle = $("#principle").val();
  let interest = $("#interest-rate").val();
  let interest2 = $("#interest-rate-two").val();
  let calc = principle / 100 * interest / 100 * interest2;
  // divide principle by 100% to get 1%, multiply by interest(35%). 
  // divide that to get 1% of the total after the first interest rate
  // multiply by interest rate 2 to get the final calculation
  $(".result").text(calc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calculator" class="calculator">
  <label class="title">Savings Calulator : Basic Compound Interest</label>
  <hr/>
  <br/>
  <label>Input ($)</label>
  <input type="number" id="principle" value="0" min="0">
    <br/>
  <label>Interest Rate (%)</label>
  <input type="number" id="interest-rate" value="35" min="0">
  </br>
    <label>Interest Rate (%)</label>
  <input type="number" id="interest-rate-two" value="19" min="0">
    <br/>
  <hr/>
  <div id="calc">calculate</div>
  <div id="calc-result" class="result">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want your inputs in `(%)` then it will be `35` not `0.35` - so you just need to divide by 100 as part of the calculation.  Also, check your inputs for valid data.

Comment: Thank you, it's very helpful Would you know how to show this:The fixed number of hours that may be shown here is 370 hours (46 weeks x 8 hours per week = 368 hours = 370 hours rounded up)

Comment: ***edit*** as @freedomn-m mentioned i overlooked the % and used the 0.35 value over 35%. new calculation handles 35 rather than 0.35

Comment: @RamondeVries apologies if unclear, that comment was directed at OP rather than you - you kept that part as the original